# A little help needed on my project

Tags: java, recursion

I'm developing a JAVA project as my assigment. In a part of LinkedList class I stucked on recursion. Can anyone help me about writing this function? The question is How to Write a recursive instance method for the LinkedList class that prints the linked list instance in reverse order and lenght of the LinkedList lenght (I guess with different two functions)? 
My LinkedList class is like:

```
public class Node
{
public int data;
public Node next;
public Node (int data)
{
this.data = data;
}
}

public class LinkedList
{
private Node first;
public LinkedList
{
first = null;
}
}
```

For ex this is my insert recursive method for LinkedList

```
private void insertRec(Node n, int data)
{
if(n == null)
{
Node newNode = new Node(data);
return newNode;
}

if(data > n.data)
n.next = insertRec(n.next,data);
return n;
}
```

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far?  What specific problems are you having?

Comment: It might help if you started off with an algorithm and asked for input/help instead of asking for the entire function.

Comment: @Oli I cand write any code for these, but I wrote some for other questions. I'm going to post it, please can you check if its true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void reversePrint (LinkedList l)
  {
    if (l != null) {
      reversePrint(l.next);
      System.out.println(l.value);
    }
  }
```

For computing the length of the linked list

```
 public static int length (LinkedList l)
  {
    if (l == null)
      return 0;
    else
      return 1 + length(l.next);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the Node class:

```
public void printReverse() {

  if ( next != null ) {
    next.printReverse();
  }

  System.out.println(data);
}
```

and this to the `LinkedList` class:

```
print void printReverse() {
  System.out.println("(");

  if ( first == null ) {
    first.printReverse();
  }

  System.out.println(")");
}
```

You should try to change this code to print the list normally :) (It's a very simple change).

Comment: I think using recursive function in my class is better :) Thank you. Do you know about lenght of my LinkedList recursive method?

Comment: It's a variation on the printReverse method. You need to know that the length of a list can be calculated as the length of tail (the sublist starting just after the head) plus 1 :).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing this is to call your traverse method with the "current" list element (which starts as the first list node).  The method checks to see if it has the last element of the list.  If it doesn't, recursively call the method with the next element.  Then print out the value of the current element.